# New cgit/gitolite not allowing access to copied repostiory

Tags: gitolite, cgit

Is there any way to get a log of what failed during cloning?

But cloning my copied repository is denied:

```
$ git clone git@192.168.8.20:linux linux-999
Cloning into 'linux-999'...
FATAL: R any linux user1 DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

The gitolite.conf file:

```
 ...
repo testing
    RW+     =   @all

repo linux
    RW+     =   @all
```

The repositories on the server are all owned by the gitolite user.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I hadn't run:

```
gitolite setup
```